# Java Memory Profiling application - memory high before garbage collection

Tags: java, heap-memory

I am running a Java profiler on my application which has MAX mem usage setup as 256 MB.

STEP 1.  I started my application, and checked USED HEAP space = 24 MB

STEP 2. I then executed function which I was profiling, and Checked USED HEAP space = 45 MB shows as LIVE Objects

STEP 3.  I then executed Garbage Collection, and checked USED HEAP space = 24 MB.

Question: Should I be concerned about why the memory grows by 20 MB during step 2? As the GC cleans out the heap space, is step 2 immaterial?

My concern is that if many threads concurrently execute STEP 2, will I have a scenario of OUT of MEMORY? Or does GC take care of it?

Comment: Did you execute GC manually? When the JVM needs more memory, GC is done automatically

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting in an answer to this question.  Yes, if you run more threads than you have allocated enough memory to support, you will get out of memory errors.